# Lottie animation slows down my other native wpf animations

Tags: wpf, lottie

I added two Lottie animations to my wpf project and when both native animations and lottie animations are rendered at the same time, the native ones have slown down to almost a crawl.
Is there any way to pre-render the animations? Or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I figured out is to load the animations when I need them and dispose of them when I'm done. I am using them in button, so my solution for now is, when the button appears, to load it:

```
 animation = new LottieAnimationView();
 animation.SetAnimationAsync("Assets/Images/image.json");
 animation.Scale = 1.5;
 button.Content = animation;
```

And when the button leaves the view:

```
button.Content = "";
animation.Dispose();
```

I am not a fan of the solution, but at least the other animations that run at the other times aren't lagging anymore.